# How to change the rotation of my blender model at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press the down key the dinosaur should crouch (which it does), but it stays in the air and has rotated. I already checked the models and they have the same export options. Also in the scene view, it can see that the model does not experiment with any change.

The models do not have animations, I manage everything from a gameobject to which I added a mesh renderer, mesh filter, and script. You can see it right there in the pictures.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR71Q.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY6tn.png)

this is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class manageTrex : MonoBehaviour {
    public Mesh[] mMeshes;
    public Mesh[] meshDown;
    int num=0,num2=0;
    float velz,velx;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Invoke("trexRun",0.10f);
        GameObject.Find ("Plane").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("images/sand_dessert") as Texture;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
            velx = -2.5f;
            GameObject.Find ("gobjTrex").transform.Translate(new Vector3(velx*Time.deltaTime,0f,0f));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
            velx = 2.5f;
            GameObject.Find ("gobjTrex").transform.Translate(new Vector3(velx*Time.deltaTime,0f,0f));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("down")) {
            Invoke("trexDown",0.10f);
            CancelInvoke ("trexRun");
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKeyUp ("down")){
            Invoke("trexRun",0.10f);
            CancelInvoke ("trexDown");
        }
    }
    
    void trexRun(){
        string[] arr_model = {"trex_walk_1","trex_walk_2","trex_walk_3"};
        
        if (num > 2) {
            num = 0;
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("acum: "+num+", mesh: "+arr_model[num]);
    
            GameObject.Find("gobjTrex").GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = mMeshes[num];
            num++;
        }
        Invoke ("trexRun",0.10f);
    }
    
    void trexDown(){
        string[] arr_model = {"trex_down1g2_fbx","trex_down2g2_fbx"};

        if (num2 > 1) {
            num2 = 0;
        } else {
            GameObject.Find("gobjTrex").GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = meshDown[num2];
            num2++;
        }

        Invoke ("trexDown",0.10f);
    }
}
```

I tried rotate the model in different axes before exporting it, but the result it's the same. as you can see in this picture.

[the problem itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwbP1.png)

---

this is how the blender models looks like:

[dinosaur_run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuSHM.png)

[dinosaur_crouch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiHg2.png)

-------------------------------------------
If it helps, here are these links:

3d models:
https://mega.nz/file/nSpGETSQ#4ukMPby5fawUe9F-cStXU4sOTQGU1975fcj9iijgU1I

unity project:
https://mega.nz/file/bOB2lTxa#V05sf8W6D5ayC-xHspuxAzGXg-UeswvOEeP_D5TfU-A

Comment: Are all the imported models correctly rotated?

Comment: yes, the models has the same orientation

Comment: If the mesh components on the original models are not the root nodes, you may compare the rotation and scale properties of the child transforms and apply them to the GameObject, and also check the scale factor property in the model importer to see if it is negative. If it's convenient, you may share the fbx files.

Comment: Dude, you made it all with `GameObject.Find`. this sings game performance Fatiha.

Comment: The rotation of the down models is (-90,0,0), the rotation of the walk models is (-90,0,-180). You can either set the rotation or check the export configuration.

Comment: the models are ok, the problem is when I put any model inside an empty gameobject

Comment: Just a note, for better performance, cache the gobjTrex object, and if you need to call GameObject.Find(), do it once in the Start function, assigning it to gobjTrex. Then you won't have to call every time you move.

Comment: I exported the models as .obj and problem solved :)